# Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 5.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 yet it's targeting net 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-5.0

I am migrating to .NET 5.0 from .Net Core 3.1.

I keep getting this error message:

> Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 5.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1) / win-x86. Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 5.0.0 supports: net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0)

I understand what it is saying, but I don't know why it is saying it.

My project targets .NET 5.0.

My csproj file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>5e2f8086-7a94-402a-bd2a-4160e9236c8f</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>


 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I'm unsure why it's telling me about 3.1.

I manually removed the bin and obj folders, tried to update all nuget packages, and clean/rebuild the project, but I get the same issue each time.v

I am on Visual Studio 16.8.2.

**EDIT**

I should point out, the error is not a compiler error! If I debug in Visual Studio, the website spins up fine. This error message only occurs when I try to publish

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turned out it was this error, in that the target framework for publish was still set to .NET Core 3.1

[image]

Answer (score 7):

you can install the microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer version 3.1.x by clicking on the version dropdown in nuget, if you haven't moved to 5.

Answer (score 4):

You can check the following steps to solve your problem.

1. Download NET 5.0 SDK [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks).
2. You need `Visual Studio 16.8` or later to use .NET 5.0 on Windows. Please confirm your VS version.
3. The package:`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />` is
   obsolete, please remove the reference in the project file.
4. Clean and rebuild.

Comment: All done, same issue. I have NET 5.0 . If I run `dotnet --version` it shows 5.0.100. I am on Visual Studio 16.8.2. I had actually already removed that line of code (good spot) and again, same issue!!

Comment: If you create a new .netcore3.1 project and then edit it to .net5 and  reference these packages, will it go wrong?

Comment: I tried to do this and it worked well on my project.

Comment: Or you can create a new .net5.0 project then reference these packages,you can try.

Comment: Hi @MyDaftQuestions,Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: No, sorry. I created a new .net5 project., copied the `.cs` and `chsmlt` files, the contents of `wwwroot` and the same issue continues

Comment: You can see [here](https://samlearnsazure.blog/2020/10/02/upgrading-our-net-core-3-1-project-to-net-5/) may find you problem.

Answer (score 1):

First I just took a quick look and I think it could be related that you have some libraries that the version doesn't support 3.1 and that's why you are getting the error.

But just to be sure: [There is a Microsoft guide for this specific migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: I'm migrating from 3.1 and they all worked fine when targeting 3.1

Answer (score 1):

It's compatible with `3.1.17`. try it
[image]

Comment: This answers MY question: "How can I use JwtBearer in my core 3.1 app? When I try to install the nuget package I get this error ..."